# Invalid use of group functions

Tags: php, mysql

What causes this error?:

> Invalid use of group functions

Here is the sql code causing the error:

```
$sql_data = "UPDATE `database1`.`users` SET `balance` = MIN(`balance` + 5) 
WHERE ('" . $session->value('user_id') . "') ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql_data = "UPDATE `database1`.`users` SET `balance` = MIN(`balance`) + 5  
WHERE ('" . $session->value('user_id') . "') "
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions require an aggregation caused by a `GROUP BY` clause. Without one, the query is invalid.

Comment: @Madhivanan: The fact that MySQL will happily execute invalid queries doesn't make me wrong.

Comment: You are right. I just told you it is valid in mysql. Mysql has lot of behaviours that contradicts to ANSI standard

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the error is, I'm assuming it is stemming from `MIN(balance + 5)`. I think you mean `MIN(balance) + 5` - MIN should only take a column name, not an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE database1.users a
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT id, MIN(balance)
         FROM database1.users
         WHERE user_id= ('" . $session->value('user_id') . "')
         GROUP BY id
        ) b
        ON a.id = b.id
WHERE user_id = ('" . $session->value('user_id') . "');
```